# From admin edit user page query either the user_nicename or username field value of the user profile being edited or viewed

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, profiles

I want to query the Username field when im in the edit user page and profile page

[image]

and fill it into a custom field i have at the end of the form
[image]

I have my own reasons for the second username field I just want to populate it with the profile Username thanks

Comment: Hey welcome demo7up, to me its not that clear what exactly your trying to do. Can you explain a bit more? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey ok so I have custom fields in wordpress user profiles that have predefined fields that users cant edit. When I as an admin go to edit a users page there is second username field. I want the second username field to query the original username field value and prepopulate the second with the same value as the user im editing. Currently when I hit save the second username field saves with my username instead of the user thats being edited.

Comment: How have you added those fields? You should add the query function to your code when you setup those fields up.

Comment: All the fields are added and working properly. i just dont know what the query is to query the username from the profile im editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the username of a user you can use the `get_userdata()` function.

Pass it the users ID

```
$user = get_userdata($user_id);
```

Then the have access to the username or user_login as its called

```
echo $user->user_login;
```

You can read more about this function here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

Or if you need to get the user by other information, see `get_user_by()`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/

Comment: You are the best!!!!!!! Thats exactly what i was looking for I kept using `global $current_user; update_usermeta( $user_id, 'fw_name', $current_user->user_login );` This fixed my issue thanks again its been driving me nuts! Everything is working as it should now with your code!